# Ubuntu creating tmux session from shell results in "Error connecting to tmux"

Tags: ubuntu, shell, tmux

I have a server running in EC2 and every time I need to deploy a new version of my app I run the following script:

```
#Kills tmux and kills <my-app> process
pkill -f tmux
pkill ./my-app

#Removes old bot files and extracts new ones
rm -rf myapp/*
unzip publish.zip -d myapp

#Grants permissions to the botfile
chmod 750 myapp/*
chown root:ubuntu myapp/*

#Starts bot and creates a new tmux session
pkill -USR1 tmux
tmux new_session -d -s  session-name './myapp/my-app'
```

The last line to start a new `tmux` session and runs the app works fine if I invoke it myself from the terminal, however if I run it from within the script results in the following error:

`error connecting to /tmp/tmux-1001/default (No such file or directory)`

Reading other stack exchange posts it was suggested to add `pkill -USR1 tmux` to signal tmux although it did not solve the problem. How can I address this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue fixed by not detaching the session, removing `-d`. There is also a typo in `new_session`, should be `new-session`.

Replacing the last line with

```
tmux new-session -s myapp './my-app/MyApp'
```

Creates a new session `myapp` which I then access with

```
tmux a -t myapp
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message you are getting:

```
error connecting to /tmp/tmux-1000/default (No such file or directory)
```

implies that there is no tmux session to connect to, so your script appears to not be creating a tmux session. When I run your command

```
tmux new_session -d -s  session-name './myapp/my-app'
```

I get the following error:

```
unknown command: new_session
```

However running:

```
tmux new -d -s TestSession -c myapp/my-app
```

works as expected.  This is on:
**Linux #142-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 26 12:12:57 UTC 2022**
running:
**tmux 3.0a**

Comment: When using your command in my script, it does not error out but running `tmux ls` shows no sessions running at all and if I simply try to connect to the named session (i.e. `tmux a -t SessionName`) I get `no server running on /tmp/tmux-1000/default`.

Comment: Heinzen for some reason tmux is failing to start a detached session - does it work from the command line?  if your script is a bash script does adding `set -euo pipefail` and see if that shows any errors...

Comment: Also what is the output of `ls -lta /dev/ptmx`

Comment: I fixed the issue by not using `-d` (detaching seemed to cause an issue as you pointed out) and there was a typo in `new_session`, should be `new-session`. It works as intended now.